# How to remove a string that includes specific strings but with different length inside the string?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have a log file that I want to delete some specific parts. The following shows a part of log file:

```
I0216 10:18:04.720626 31559 solver.cpp:273] Solving 
I0216 10:18:04.720630 31559 solver.cpp:274] Learning Rate Policy: step
I0216 10:18:05.242708 31559 solver.cpp:219] Iteration 0 (0 iter/s, 0.522037s/50 iters), loss = 1.60944
I0216 10:18:05.242750 31559 solver.cpp:238]     Train net output #0: accuracy = 0
I0216 10:18:05.242763 31559 solver.cpp:238]     Train net output #1: loss = 1.60944 (* 1 = 1.60944 loss)
I0216 10:18:05.242785 31559 sgd_solver.cpp:105] Iteration 0, lr = 1e-10
I0216 10:18:22.386440 31559 solver.cpp:219] Iteration 50 (2.91648 iter/s, 17.144s/50 iters), loss = 1.60944
I0216 10:18:22.386497 31559 solver.cpp:238]     Train net output #0: accuracy = 0.643982
I0216 10:18:22.386509 31559 solver.cpp:238]     Train net output #1: loss = 1.60944 (* 1 = 1.60944 loss)
I0216 10:18:22.386515 31559 sgd_solver.cpp:105] Iteration 50, lr = 1e-10
I0216 10:18:39.549926 31559 solver.cpp:219] Iteration 100 (2.91313 iter/s, 17.1637s/50 iters), loss = 1.60944
I0216 10:18:39.550071 31559 solver.cpp:238]     Train net output #0: accuracy = 1
I0216 10:18:39.550087 31559 solver.cpp:238]     Train net output #1: loss = 1.60944 (* 1 = 1.60944 loss)
I0216 10:18:39.550093 31559 sgd_solver.cpp:105] Iteration 100, lr = 1e-10
I0216 10:18:56.714752 31559 solver.cpp:219] Iteration 150 (2.91292 iter/s, 17.1649s/50 iters), loss = 1.60944
I0216 10:18:56.714824 31559 solver.cpp:238]     Train net output #0: accuracy = 0.624222
I0216 10:18:56.714838 31559 solver.cpp:238]     Train net output #1: loss = 1.60944 (* 1 = 1.60944 loss)
I0216 10:18:56.714845 31559 sgd_solver.cpp:105] Iteration 150, lr = 1e-10
I0216 10:19:13.893241 31559 solver.cpp:219] Iteration 200 (2.91059 iter/s, 17.1787s/50 iters), loss = 1.60944
I0216 10:19:13.893450 31559 solver.cpp:238]     Train net output #0: accuracy = 1
I0216 10:19:13.893467 31559 solver.cpp:238]     Train net output #1: loss = 1.60944 (* 1 = 1.60944 loss)
I0216 10:19:13.893473 31559 sgd_solver.cpp:105] Iteration 200, lr = 1e-10
I0216 10:19:31.094591 31559 solver.cpp:219] Iteration 250 (2.90674 iter/s, 17.2014s/50 iters), loss = 1.60944
I0216 10:19:31.094650 31559 solver.cpp:238]     Train net output #0: accuracy = 0.61937
I0216 10:19:31.094662 31559 solver.cpp:238]     Train net output #1: loss = 1.60944 (* 1 = 1.60944 loss)
I0216 10:19:31.094667 31559 sgd_solver.cpp:105] Iteration 250, lr = 1e-10
I0216 10:19:48.290045 31559 solver.cpp:219] Iteration 300 (2.90772 iter/s, 17.1956s/50 iters), loss = 1.60944
I0216 10:19:48.290187 31559 solver.cpp:238]     Train net output #0: accuracy = 0.959229
I0216 10:19:48.290205 31559 solver.cpp:238]     Train net output #1: loss = 1.60944 (* 1 = 1.60944 loss)
I0216 10:19:48.290210 31559 sgd_solver.cpp:105] Iteration 300, lr = 1e-10
I0216 10:20:05.504201 31559 solver.cpp:219] Iteration 350 (2.90457 iter/s, 17.2142s/50 iters), loss = 1.60944
I0216 10:20:05.504257 31559 solver.cpp:238]     Train net output #0: accuracy = 0.772217
I0216 10:20:05.504271 31559 solver.cpp:238]     Train net output #1: loss = 1.60944 (* 1 = 1.60944 loss)
```

As it can be seen, there are some lines that start with `31559 solver.cpp:219] Iteration`

I would like, without changing the other lines of the file, to change only these lines, for example, this one: FROM

```
   ... solver.cpp:219] Iteration 14750 (2.9004 iter/s, 17.239s/50 iters), loss = 1.60934
```

To

```
... solver.cpp:219] Iteration 14750, loss = 1.60934
.
.
.
```

This means I want to remove the sub-string `(2.9004 iter/s, 17.239s/50 iters)` from the lines which includes the above-mentioned lines, but the other lines remain unchanged. 
Thanks

I would like to remove those parts in a line that include `(2.8995 iter/s, 17.2444s/50 iters)`, the length of this string may differ from each other. This part starts with `(` and continues with a number (which may be different from the other line and continues with`iter/s,` and again a number and ends with `iters)`.

AS @delca85 suggested the pattern is this:

```
p = "(\(\d*[.]?\d* iter/s\,\s\d*[.]?\d*)(s/[0-9]+)?(\siters\))"
```

Does anyone have a suggestion? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made an additional assumption about the second part of your string, that it is a number with`s/number`. I hope I am not being wrong, anyway, in that case, please tell me, I would be happy to find another solution for you.

This is my proposal for you:

```
import re

string = "I0216 11:42:50.047427 31559 solver.cpp:219] Iteration 14750 (2.9004 iter/s, 17.239s/50 iters), loss = 1.60934 I0216 11:42:50.047472 31559 solver.cpp:238]     Train net output \#0: accuracy = 1\" "

p = "\(\d*[.]?\d* iter/s\, \d*[.]?\d*s/[0-9]+ iters\)"
pattern = re.compile(p)
for l in pattern.findall(string): 
    print l
```

I hope I am helping you!

**s/50 optional**
This is a solution you could use in case of `s/50` is optional in the second part of your string:

```
import re

string = "I0216 11:42:50.047427 31559 solver.cpp:219] Iteration 14750 (2.9004 iter/s, 17.239s/50 iters), loss = 1.60934 I0216 11:42:50.047472 31559 solver.cpp:238]     Train net output \#0: accuracy = 1\" "
string = string + "I0216 11:42:50.047427 31559 solver.cpp:219] Iteration 14750 (2.9004 iter/s, 17.239 iters), loss = 1.60934 I0216 11:42:50.047472 31559 solver.cpp:238]     Train net output \#0: accuracy = 1\" " 
p = "(\(\d*[.]?\d* iter/s\,\s\d*[.]?\d*)(s/[0-9]+)?(\siters\))"
pattern = re.compile(p)
for l in pattern.findall(string): 
    print ''.join(l)
```

**Open file, read line, match pattern and replace line in file**

```
import re

p = "(\(\d*[.]?\d* iter/s\,\s\d*[.]?\d*)(s/[0-9]+)?(\siters\))"
pattern = re.compile(p)
for line in fileinput.input("file.txt", inplace=1):
    for m in pattern.findall(line): 
        string = ''.join(m)
        if string in line:
            line = line.replace(string, "")
    sys.stdout.write(line)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, how can I open the file and find `p = "\([0-9\.]+ iter/s\, [0-9\.]+s/[0-9]+ iters\)"` and remove the string from the file. Should not program read the lines? Thanks

Comment: @S.EB I have added replacing line in file. I hope this could finally help you and you would accept and upvote my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. unfortunately,  it is not working since the `string` that you have brought here is not same in the lines. the iteration numbers keeps on changing

Comment: @S.EB: I edited my code in order to replace only the line with regex match.

Comment: Thank you very much, what we can replace for string becoz `string` is not same and there is not only one string in the file? but it includes  the following because of that I added this line `if 'solver.cpp:219] Iteration ' in line and 'loss = ' in line`

Comment: @S.EB I think I have finally understood what you are looking for. Please, look at my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the regular expression module for this (called 're'), which can help you quickly isolate sub-strings.

Here is the code:

```
import re

file = open('your_file_with_correct_path')
file_content = file.read()

#The string you provided
#No need to do the below string definition as you will use the file_content
#str = '   I0216 11:42:50.047427 31559 solver.cpp:219] Iteration 14750 (2.9004 iter/s, 17.239s/50 iters), loss = 1.60934 I0216 11:42:50.047472 31559 solver.cpp:238] Train net output #0: accuracy = 1'

sub_tring = re.findall('\(\d+.*\)', file_content)

for element in sub_string:
    #add element to the file you want

#save the file where you added the elements
```

sub_string will be a list of all sub strings that match the pattern that you ask for with the first argument of the `findall` method.

I recommend that you look at the various special characters that are used in [regex](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) as this will be really useful for cleaning strings generally.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your response, this `str` is just one type of the lines in the log file, How we can change the program read a line and process the line whether includes this for example `(2.9004 iter/s, 17.239s/50 iters)` , if yes, then remove that part from the line and save it.

Comment: You can read your whole log file, so in your case str would be str = log_file.read(). Then you can create the sub_string variable I added in the previous code. This will give you a list of all the patterns that match (i.e. your ( ... iters) in your log file. To save it you just then have to iterate through the sub_string list and add each element to the document you want. Then save the document at the end of the process.

Comment: @S.EB I have amended my response so you can see the whole process behind my previous comment. This should help you get what you need.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, but I am not that much familiar with python. I edited my question.

Comment: Just seen your amendment to your question. So what you actually want is your log file without the iter parts right?